# How to change DATE on Zacks Calendar via url?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I have this URL: https://www.zacks.com/earnings/earnings-calendar

I'm trying to change the date to the next day..or any day other than the current so I can get the list of stocks. I'm scrapping this via python and building a table using pyqt.

How do I switch the date?

So far I was able to get this: https://www.zacks.com/earnings/earnings-calendar?date=1405317600
The **"earnings-calendar?date=1405317600"** gives me the date **July 14th, 2017**, but I don't understand the format.

How do I get **June 7th,  2017** via the URL or Python code. The Zacks API via Quandl.com doesn't help.

Second question, as I have not done much web development, is there a way to list all querys of a site? not even sure that's the correct vocab, but i'm taking about the 'methods'(python lingo) of a site. the stuff after the .com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "earnings-calendar?date=1405317600" gives me the date July 14th, 2017, but I don't understand the format.

That format looks like a UNIX `time_t` -- a time measured in seconds since midnight (GMT) on January 1st, 1970.

My tools translate that time as `Sun Jul 13 23:00:00 2014`. That doesn't quite match up with the date you got -- it's three years and one hour early! -- but you can still probably add/subtract 86400 seconds at a time to move it around. For instance, if you wanted to adjust the date from July 14th to June 7th, you'd need to subtract 35 days, or 3,024,000 seconds, from the time (giving you `?date=1402293600`).

You might have to tweak the time by an hour (3600 seconds) around the Daylight Savings Time gap, depending on how the site works internally.

> Second question, as I have not done much web development, is there a way to list all querys of a site?

Nope. Sorry.

The list of paths and query parameters accepted by a web application is completely internal to the application. There's no way to get that list without reading its source code.